# Problem in running a project with aspectJ in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, ajc

I am trying to run a project with aspectJ, rather than Java, in IntelliJ IDEA. I had done it before by simply putting "aspectj-1.9.6" in a "Lib" folder and setting the folder "as Library". But I tried it again today and it is not working. I think it might be because I have updated my IntelliJ to version "2022.2.3". I saw in [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/aspectj.html) that for intelliJ version "2021.1", one should select "ajc" as the project compiler in IntellJ. But it seems that there is no such compiler option in IntelliJ version "2022.2" (as I looked at [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/java-compiler.html)  and also searched in [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/getting-started.html)).

I also tried to install and enable "AspectJ weaver" plugin, but I encounter the following error: "Plugin 'AspectJ weaver' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA.". Someone has had the same problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069035/plugin-aspectj-weaver-failed-to-initialize-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-co), but the answer doesn't work for me, as it refers to [this link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4679-aspectj), which is not compatible with IntelliJ version 2022.2.3:
[image]

So, I wonder whether aspectJ is not supported any more in IntelliJ?
Does any one has any suggestion that I could use it with this version of IntelliJ? I do really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make sure that [AspectJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4679-aspectj) plugin is [installed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) and enabled.

Comment: Hi @EgorKlepikov, thanks for your reply. I had tried to install "AspectJ" weaver plugin, but  I encountered this error "Plugin 'AspectJ weaver' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA". Even when I open the link you mentioned as [AspectJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4679-aspectj), I see this message just below the "Get" button: "Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3)"

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I also updated my question by adding problems regarding installing the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA is compatible with AspectJ. I am running the plugin on 2022.2.3 without any problems. But I use IDEA Ultimate, you use Community. Did you notice this in your screenshot?

> Compatible with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes I had noticed that. But I wanted to use IDEA community, and strangely it worked before.